# Binomial convergence to Normal

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Consider a Bernoulli random variable denoted $B_i$, representing a coinflip.

It is clear that a Random variable:

$$X_n:=\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}B_i$$

is a Binomial random variable: $X_n \sim Bin(n,p)$. Using CLT, we have that:

\begin{equation}
\label{1}
\frac{X_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\to^{D}N(0,1)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

It is well known that a Normal distribution might be used as an approximation for the Binomial, and in fact I have come across the following statement (again, using CLT):

\begin{equation}
\label{2}
X_n \to^{D}N\left(np, np(1-p)\right) \tag{2}
\end{equation}

**Question**: I wonder if \ref{2} above is rigorous? It is obvious that as $n\to\infty$, both the mean $np$ and the variance $np(1-p)$ diverge. This also makes sense logically, because as the number of coinflips tends to infinity, one would of course expect that the 'expected value' of successes $np$ will also tend to infinity.

So can one use \ref{2} with mathematical rigor, or is only \ref{1} mathematically rigorous?

Comment: (2) does not even make sense. You cannot have $n$ in the limit.

Comment: (1) is correct.  (2) has no meaning; at best, you can say the RHS of (2) may be used as an approximated distribution of $X_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by rigorous.

Saying a succession tends to a certain limit as $n \to \infty$ means in particular thta, for $n$ large enough, the succession is close to the limit. Thus if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, for $n$ large

$$
\mathbb{P}\bigg( \frac{\bar{X}_n - \mu}{\sigma /\sqrt{n}} < t \bigg) \approx \mathbb{P}(Z < t)
$$

This can be written as

$$
\mathbb{P}(\bar{X}_n < k) \approx \mathbb{P}\bigg( \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}Z + \mu < k\bigg) = \mathbb{P}(Y < k), \quad Y\sim \mathcal{N}\bigg(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\bigg)
$$

Alternatively again we have

$$
\mathbb{P}\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i < k \bigg) \approx  \mathbb{P}(Y < k), \quad Y\sim \mathcal{N}\bigg(n\mu, n\sigma^2\bigg)
$$

This last form is the one in (2) if applied to a binomal rv.

As a side note: the binomial is symmetric for $p=1/2$ and the closer it is to $p \in \{0,1\}$ the more asymmetric it becomes. For this reason, usually, we apply the normal approximation when $np > 5$ and $n(1-p) > 5$